# Review Queue Notification Working?

Tags: support

Now that we're out of beta, I've not been seeing the review queue notifications appearing when there are items in need of review. Is this a matter of no longer having sufficient reputation for this feature to function for me or is it simply not working right now? I don't recall at what point it began, "Access to Moderator Tools" perhaps? From reading the help files, its not clear to me where this is supposed to begin as I can't find a reference to the feature at all.

Thank you for any clarification or enlightenment.

Comment: They've never worked 'properly' for me. I only ever see them when there are things in the 'Suggested Edits' queue. Definitely feels like a bug.

Comment: Earlier today, I edited the tags to add `bug`. I've always had everything show up for me that was in the queue. Now I get no notifications at all. I may try clearing my browser cache to see if it solves the issue. Note [display-a-number-near-the-review-link](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/821/display-a-number-near-the-review-link) question by SF_user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: [Found this on StackExchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726). You need 10k rep to see the notification. This changed once we got out of beta.

I should think you'd still see them. You have more than 3k rep which seems to be enough to vote to close. According to the [priveleges section](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation), you only need 500 rep to access review queues.

Comment: I'd think so too. The only thing I think I've actually lost the privilege to approve is tag wiki edits which is why I asked the question. I can't find any reason why I wouldn't be seeing the notifications. As you have over 10k, I'd expect you to see them. I'm wondering whether others with less than 10k rep are seeing them or not?

Comment: I have the opposite problem. I see a 3 next to the Review link, but there is nothing in the queue.

Comment: From the link you referenced *"It is also cached, so may or may not be very accurate depending on the amount of ongoing activity in /review at any given time."* That would seem to explain why nothing would be in the queue despite it showing there's 3 for you to review.

Comment: It also isn't user specific - so if there are still items in the queue I've reviewed, it will still display.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the queue reappeared for me tonight and I only have a rep of 4389 at this moment in time. Makes me wonder if the post linked to in your edit is still valid. I suppose it could also mean that something in the system is broken tonight too. (chkles)